# Injecting a context menu item into 3rd party flash object

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, google-chrome-extension

Within a Chrome extension, how can I inject items into the context menus of 3rd party flash objects?

Is it possible to simply inject items using JavaScript?

Is it possible to wrap the players in a container .swf that adds our context menu item along with the items included by the original swf?

Thanks so much for your ideas and inspiration!

**Edit:** To be clear, what I'd like to do with my extension is add a context menu item to any 3rd party Flash program. So for instance, if a user visits YouTube, I'd like to add my own menu item along with YouTube's custom items.

Comment: So basically you're in a html context and your application wraps the user web navigation (similar to google translate translating a web page)? You want to capture all Flash movies in a webpage and replace with yours with the changed ContextMenu?

Comment: @felipemaia Exactly. I'll grab all `<object>`s with jQuery, get their source and pass it to mine. My object will have a custom context menu item and it will also bring in all the custom menu items from the original.

Comment: I think this wouldn't work at all... as soon as the loaded swf tries to load anything external or act upon anything outside of its context you would encounter an endless amount of problems and probably unsolvable issues.

Comment: @Cay we considered that. Especially when it comes to external interfaces. We're going to give it a shot and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to do exactly what you and @felipemaia suggested - make use of a loader SWF that adds (or modifies) the context menu of its loaded SWF.

The original (loaded) SWF:

```
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
import flash.ui.ContextMenuItem;

var customContextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
// Comment in if you want to hide the default context menu items.
// customContextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
var sampleItem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem('Cheerio!');
customContextMenu.customItems.push(sampleItem, new ContextMenuItem('What it do?'));
this.contextMenu = customContextMenu;
```

And the loader SWF:

```
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
import flash.ui.ContextMenuItem;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, modify_context_menu);
loader.load(new URLRequest('LoadedSWF.swf'));

function modify_context_menu(event:Event):void
{
    var loadedSWF:Sprite = (event.target as LoaderInfo).content as Sprite;  
    var loadedContextMenu:ContextMenu = loadedSWF.contextMenu;  
    loadedContextMenu.customItems.push(new ContextMenuItem('Parent Menu Item'), new ContextMenuItem('Parent what it be?'));

    this.contextMenu = loadedContextMenu;
}
```

Note that if you need finer grain control you can also modify the context menu on individual InteractiveObject subclasses:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
var spriteContextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
spriteContextMenu.customItems.push(new ContextMenuItem('Instance specific menu item!'));
sprite.contextMenu = spriteContextMenu;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to test this until Monday. But the bounty is yours on good faith that this code actually works ;)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can edit these context menues, to be honest. but my flash knowledge is pretty solidly out of date, so maybe things have changed.

however, why not parse the page, grab the video to be shared, and share it directly? depending on the site, many provide oembed information you can make use of.

Comment: Thanks for the response. oEmbed support is something we're adding soon, but we were hoping to inject the context menu item to simplify the UX. Our competitors prefer an overlay style interface that we're not fans of.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is have a loader swf that will load the required swf, that way you can wrap the desired application and have full access to the context menu.

Comment: This is a solution we thought might work. Can you provide a working example? The bounty is yours if you can!

Comment: This looks like a relevant page in the docs. I don't have a Flash dev environment set up or else I'd try it myself. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html

Comment: Indeed that link you found has what you need to write an swf loader and wrap your target swf. Without the exact details of your project though, I cannot give you more information than you can find there, if you can explain better what you need, I probably can help you further.

Comment: Just edited my question to be as clear as possible. Not sure what else to add.

Comment: So basically you're in a html context and your application wraps the user web navigation (similar to google translate translating a web page)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible unless the Flash file has some code that will use [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) to load some context items, like this:

```
function loadContext():void
{
    // Vars
    var cmi:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;

    contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();

    for(var i:String in cmi)
    {
        var item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem(i);

        item.addEventListener(
            ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, 
            function(e:ContextMenuEvent):void
            {
                navigateToURL(
                    new URLRequest(cmi[i])
                );
            }
        );
    }

    contextMenu.customItems.push(item);
}

loadContext();
```

Wouldn't want my flash game appearing on some website that's injecting advertisements or something profane into my context menu. That wouldn't make me look very good.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over the original Flash files. Thanks for your input, though!